# Qt- How to sense multiple Pushbutton pressed in the same time?

Tags: qt, virtual, qpushbutton, piano

I am making a virtual piano in QT with a touchscreen-sensable board.
I made virtual-piano-keys with Qpushbutton, so I have to sense a couple of QPushbuttons pressed in the same time. How can I do this? or Is there a better idea to make a virtual piano with Qt?

Comment: A simple idea is maybe to just save a list (or map etc) of pressed buttons. e.g. add the pressed buttons to a list and if it's released remove it again so you always know if multiple buttons are down at the same time

Comment: maybe you can just use `QTouchEvent` to determine what buttons are pressed, but that depends on your application

Comment: How about each button gets a signal that is emitted when the button is pressed, and a signal that is emitted when the button is released. Then when it is pressed down you can start playing a sound and when it is released you can stop playing the sound. I don't think it's necessary for a button to know if other ones are pressed as well. However, if that was necessary, you could add a counter that is increased when a button is pressed down and decreased when it is released. Then you would always know how many buttons are pressed at a time.